# Work with Django forms without widgets

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I would like to use a model to make a user registration form but I would like to use my own HTML code without using widgets. I supose it is possible but I don't know how to build it, I'm beginner with Django. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Django provides most of the attributes for each field in the form that you will need to build your own HTML.

For example:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            <input type="text" name="{{ field.html_name }}" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" value="{{ field.value }}">
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```